# Blazeds - Spring - Messaging - Selective server data push

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have a flex UI which communicates with server using spring blazeds. I have a very typical requirement of Live data streaming on a panel in UI.

Requirement is like this,
We have an object say, Person and server keeps pushing its data on blazeds message destination  where UI panel consumer has subscribed and hence user can see this live data in a panel.

1. User can open multiple panels in same browser to view data for different Persons at the same time (e.g id=1,2,3 respectively)
2. There can be multiple UI users who may be viewing the same data for person id=1 at a given time, lets say.

Basically I want to separate data between UI panels. UI panel opened for person id=1 must not display data of that for person id=2. I am doing this using headers-selectors, but apparently I found out that the differentiation to select and display what data happens on UI which is causing performance issues. I learned that using subtopics may improve performance.

But, before proceeding for it, I want to know, will UI browser end up in receiving data irrespective of subtopic assigned to data and then consumer will decide to accept it or not? If so, the problem will remain the same. Is there any good way to achieve the objective.

-Miral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is faster to use subtopics, check this article - http://cornelcreanga.com/2010/09/blazeds-message-selectors-vs-subtopics/

The message filtering will be done only on the server, no mater what approach are you going to choose.

As a suggestion you should check this [guide](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/livecycle/pdfs/lcdses2_performance_brief.pdf) and create some scenarios, if you think that you can hit some performance problems.

Comment: Thanks Cornel. Guide was really helpful.

Comment: Performance guide given above was regarding to LCDS. Performance figures mentioned there are applicable to BlazeDS as well? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The BlazeDS performance will be behind LCDS. There are a couple of links in the guide which can guide you to build your own performance test.